# Почему ifstream не воспринимает абсолютный путь к файлу в linux?

Tags: c++, linux, файловая-система

Так работает:

```
ifstream list("../../../.Alarm_clock/output.txt");
```

Так - нет:

```
ifstream list("$HOME/.Alarm_clock/output.txt");
```

Comment: А разве `$HOME` автоматически раскрывается в путь? Мне казалось, это shell делает :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Насколько я могу судить о Linux (я в нем не слишком знаток), `$HOME` - указание для оболочки подставить значение переменной среды `HOME`. Что конструктор `ifstream`, естественно, не делает.

Воспользуйтесь соответствующей функцией - как я понимаю, `getenv("HOME")`, и соберите полный путь к файлу.